# Do I need to set up a redirect for CDN URLs?

Tags: cdn

I'm in the process of adding a CDN across my site for images/files, i'm wondering for SEO, would I need to set up redirects from the non-cdn URL path to the cdn URL path? As an example:

- www.examplesite.com/images/imagehere.jpg -> cdn.examplesite.com/images/imagehere.jpg

Also i'm using absolute URLs in my code /images/imagehere.jpg, is this not possible with a CDN?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to issue 30X responses at your image server, have your CDN convert them and return the image, you'll probably need to specify some rule(s) at the CDN to handle the various responses.